# How much money can you take into Canada?

Tags: canada, money, customs-and-immigration

I'll be travelling to Canada from the UK in the near future. Is there a limit to how much money I can carry with me? Ideally I'd like to take 5,000 CAD in order to sort out some legitimate family matters, but am concerned about any issues this may cause.

Do you have any other advice that could help avoid potential issues?

Comment: Well I know this Nigerian prince... ;)

Comment: I don't recommend taking such big amount of money in cash. Try to put them in debit card (or international bank account) and withdraw them from destination country.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be fine. [According to the Canadian Border Services Agency website](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5082-eng.html#s5x4):

> If you are importing or exporting monetary instruments **equal to or
>   greater than CAN$10,000 (or the equivalent in a foreign currency)**, you
>   must report the amount to the CBSA when you arrive or before you leave
>   Canada. This applies to either cash or other monetary instruments.

Even if you do want to bring in more cash than the CAN$10,000 limit, you are allowed to do so - [you just have to declare it in accordance to Canadian customs laws](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5052-eng.html).